# Number of days between current date and date field

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have this problem if anyone can help.
There is a field `(date)` in my table `(table1)` that is a date in the format `3/31/1988 (M/D/y)`, and my necessity is to define how many days have passed since that date.

I have tried to give this instruction

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) AS days
FROM table1
```

But it gives back 'null' and I think this happens because the two date formats are different (CURDATE() is YMD.....

Is it correct? can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y')) AS days
FROM table1
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3971/2)

Comment: CURDATE() return date format like Y-m-d. So if both date format is not match then the DATEDIFF function return NULL. Hence  date format should be same like below:
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS days
FROM table1

Answer (score 2):

Your `DATE` field should have `DATE` or `DATETIME` format to be used as `DATEDIFF` argument correctly.

Also `DATE` is MySQL keyword and I am not sure that you can use it as valid field name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for accurate result

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`)), '%Y-%m-%d')) AS days FROM `table1`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider results without - signs that you have to follow parameters position as below :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(Big_Date,Small_Date) AS days FROM table1.
```

positive results e.g  5 (with no sign), if you place a Small date as the first parameter then it will results minus sign e.g -5.